# Use old jQuery scrollTop position on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll, scrolltop

I built a mobile navigation menu based on four tabs. The first item is the active screen of the webapp. The other 3 items are a search menu, a notifications menu and a general menu. When one of the last three tabs are clicked, they are getting `display: block` with the jQuery `show()` function.

When one of the items is clicked, the page should scroll op top. However, when the item is closed and homescreen is shown again, it should scroll back to the last known scrollposition. I've been trying to achieve it with the following code.

```
var scrollposition = $(window).scrollTop();

$("#mobilenav").on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {

    console.log(scrollposition);

    $(notificationButton).on('click', function () {
        notificationDiv.show();
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });

    if(!notificationDiv.is(e.target)
        && notificationDiv.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        notificationDiv.hide();
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollposition);
    }
});
```

Problem is that it only remembers the scrollposition when the page is being loaded. When the variable scrollposition is placed inside the .on() function, it updates the position when clicking notificationButton, which gives scrollposition the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can save status your script 
for example onTop = false;
and change status inside the script. when you need to back to top or bottom, you can check the status, and accept or change him.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a full code example with your edits in your answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you maybe provide an example of how you would implement this piece of code? I unfortunately haven't been able to solve it yet.